# Delete file with BIM360 API Issue

Tags: delete-file, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

My aim is to Upload files into a specific subfolder of the "Plans" folder. The first problem I got was that I can only upload a file with version 1, when I use the API. So I decided to copy all files from the specific folder into an archive folder. Now I can delete all files from the specific folder, that I can upload the new files to the specific folder. I am using the forge-api-dotnet-client.

I know there are two different ways of deleting files. (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/way-delete-file-version-through-forge-dm-api)

I tried both of them but they did not work.

```
    let project = 
        { Id = "projectId" 
          ProjectFilesFolder = "specificFolderId"
          UploadFolder = "destinationFolderId" }

    let itemName = "itemName"
    let itemId = "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:QCtjhnZ5TWWCASh-mQ5nmA"

    let createVersionBody fileName itemId =
        sprintf """{ 
           "jsonapi":{ 
              "version":"1.0"
           },
           "data":{ 
              "type":"versions",
              "attributes":{ 
                 "name":"%s",
                 "extension":{ 
                    "type":"versions:autodesk.bim360:Deleted",
                    "version":"1.0"
                 }
              },
              "relationships":{ 
                 "item":{ 
                    "data":{ 
                       "type":"items",
                       "id":"%s"
                    }
                 }
              }
           }
        }""" fileName itemId
        |> JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CreateVersion>

    let versionApi = VersionsApi()
    let result = versionApi.PostVersion(project.Id, (createVersionBody itemName itemId))
    result |> ignore
```

It gives me this [BAD_INPUT Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TQl7.png) and I found that I get a different id from the api than from the webpage.

ItemId from Api: "urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:QCtjhnZ5TWWCASh-mQ5nmA"

ItemId from Webpage: ["urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:EdJjPVzFQR6tlbUJ5WK-zg"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NURbc.png)

The second way I found was to do it with "DeleteObject".

```
    let project = 
        { Id = "projectId" 
          ProjectFilesFolder = "specificFolderId"
          UploadFolder = "destinationFolderId" }

    let getStorage = ifcs project

    ObjectsApi().DeleteObject(getStorage.BucketKey, getStorage.ObjectName)
```

I get this [exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1Y2G.png) .

I am using a TwoLegged Authentication and my scope is also fine.

Is there an error in my code or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Please check the post https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/delete-and-restore-file/, your 1st way should be correct, but it looks some parameters are not correct, I will check details tomorrow my time.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did this workaround, because I thought I could not upload a file if it already exists. Instead of calling "PostItem" I should call "PostVersion" to update the items version.